# Initializing an app on boot, on install and on relaunch?

Tags: android, initialization

If my app needs to do some kind of initialization on start (such as registering broadcast receivers), the standard solution is the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. It is one of the handful of broadcasts that Android 8+ will still deliver to manifest-declared receivers. So the solution is to create a `BroadcastReceiver`, declare it in the manifest with an intent filter matching `BOOT_COMPLETED` and do all initialization there.

Drawback: this code will not run until the next reboot when the app is first installed or the package is replaced. If the app crashes, the initialization is also lost—I could work around that one by subclassing `Application` and re-running the initialization stuff in its `onCreate()` method, but the user would still need to relaunch the app.

Are there any ways for an app to detect when it has just been installed, or when it has just crashed?

Comment: If im not wrong, since Android O/P your app won't even receive any broadcasts (including boot) if it was not opened at least once after installation.

Comment: "Are there any ways for an app to detect when it has just been installed" -- no. Nothing of your app will run until the user launches your app for the first time from the launcher, or until something else uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components. This has been the case since Android 3.2 or thereabouts.